# Dynamic endpoint in Redux Toolkit Query based on state

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk, rtk-query

In our system a user can be part of many organisations. Some of the endpoints we hit reflect this, for `:org/users`, `:org/tags` etc. When making requests, the endpoint should change according to the current organisation they're "viewing as".

This is complicated by the fact that some of the endpoints don't use the `:org`.

Is it possible to use the base query to seek out and change these endpoints based on a `currentOrg` that exists in the current Redux state using RTK Query? Or do I need to always pass the `org` as a parameter to whatever action I dispatch? I'm just trying to streamline the process a bit.

Currently our base query is as simple as it gets:

```js
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: API_BASE,
    credentials: 'include'
  }),
  tagTypes: ['OrgUsers', 'OrgTags'],
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getOrgUsers: builder.query({
      query: ({ org }) => `/${org}/users`,
      providesTags: ['OrgUsers']
    }),
    getOrgTags: builder.query({
      query: ({ org }) => `/${org}/tags`,
      providesTags: ['OrgTags']
    }),
    /* ... */
  })
})
```

Comment: pass the parameters to query hook?
 like `query: (args) => {
                // Destructuring Object
                const { type, userNumber } = args;
                return {
                    // Returns url with multiple args
                    url: `${type}/${userNumber}`
                }
            }
        })` and call the hook by pass the parameters `const { data } = useGetUsersQuery({type: "users", userNumber: 1});`
https://dev.to/kunalukey/multiple-parameters-in-redux-toolkit-query-rtk-query-p3b
hopefully it helps

Comment: @Jerry I was hoping for something more elegant. Something that I can do in the base query so that my application business logic doesn't need to contain org related stuff.